# Rendering problems with IO source code

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently downloaded the source for the IO scheduling app that Google released, but am having trouble using it in Android Studio. Whenever I try to view a layout, I get the error

```
Rendering Problems
Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
```

and

```
Couldn't find theme resource ?android:attr/paddingLeft for the current theme
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong in my build to cause this? Also note that the source builds fine. There are two warnings regarding httpclient:4.0.1, but otherwise the build is successful.